# Is it possible to query a table to find rows that contain non-ASCII UTF-8 letters?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table where some of the entries are partly written with "foreign" letters, e.g. greek, cyrillic or arabic letters (i.e. foreign from a west eurpoean perspective). Is it possible to create a SELECT query that only returns the rows that contains such letters?

This is a sample table

```
Table: "names"
+----+---------------+
| id | name          |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | John          |
| 2  | Jane          |
| 3  | Сергей        | <- Sergey in Cyrrilic
| 4  | Δημήτρης      | <- Dimitris in Hreek
| 5  | Adam (אדם)    | <- Adam in both European and Hebrew
| 6  | etc...        |
+----+---------------+
```

The table is collated with UTF-8 (if it's relevant to my question).

I have no idea how (or even if its possible) to write a SELECT-statement that returns the rows that contain letters from "foreign" alphabets. So, can it be done? How?

I am using MySQL / MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

The following query,

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE name NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]';
```

will return all the non-ASCII characters which is equivalent to displaying rows with foreign characters.

Comment: Thanks... it gives me ideas on how to proceed... However, the query will not return row 5 in this case. But I think I can move on from here :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE name REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z ]';
```

This query will return as a result a list of all names that have a character in any position that has not been defined in the list.

You can find mor information about the regexp function following the link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html